# Problemas con argumentos

Tags: javascript

Se me pide que procese dos o mas arrays enviados desde una función. Pero la función solo envia un argumento. No se si es que el problema esta mal formulado o si realmente es posible hacerlo. Esto es lo que he hecho hasta ahora:

```
function uniteUnique(arr) {
  var newArr=[];
  var args = Array.from(arr);

  for(i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
    if(Array.isArray(arr[i])){
      for(j=0;j<arr[i].length;j++){
        if(!newArr.includes(arr[i][j])){
          newArr.push(arr[i][j]);
        }
      }
    }else{
      newArr.push(arr[i]);
    }
  }
  return newArr;
}

uniteUnique([1, 3, 2], [5, 2, 1, 4], [2, 1]);
```

Comment: Hay la llevas, si se puede enviar un solo argumento, solo que tendrias que enviar un arreglo de arreglos...

Comment: si entiendo!!, Tienes que hacer un proceso que procese(perdón la rebundancia) dos o mas array llegando solo un parametro por argumento... es asi?

Comment: Entiendo eso, el problema es que es un ejercicio preformulado. Yo solo puedo agregar codigo dentro de la funcion. La verdad me confunde eso.

Answer (score 0):

La unica solución seria enviar un arreglo (array) de arreglos, asi solo recibes un parametro pero puedes manipular los que quieras, siempre y cuando esten adentro del argumento

Comment: Entiendo eso, el problema es que es un ejercicio preformulado. Yo solo puedo agregar codigo dentro de la funcion. La verdad me confunde eso.

Comment: Ok, Entiendo... Puedes hacer 

mirar que variable te esta llegando y como esta estructurada, (Mediante Console.log(Variable)) asi puedes ver que variable te esta llegando y puedes actualiza rlainformación de tu pregunta.

Comment: Finalmente lo he resuelto. Elimine el argumento de la funcion e hice uso del objeto **arguments** que corresponde a los argumentos enviados a una funcion y que se pueden recuperar mediante:

var args = Array.from(arguments);

Comment: He aqui mi solución final:

`function uniteUnique() {
  var newArr=[];
  var args = Array.from(arguments);
  
  for(i=0;i<args.length;i++){
    if(Array.isArray(args[i])){
      for(j=0;j<args[i].length;j++){
        if(!newArr.includes(args[i][j])){
          newArr.push(args[i][j]);
        }
      }
    }else{
      if(!newArr.includes(args[i])){
          newArr.push(args[i]);
        }
    }
  }
  
  return newArr;
}

uniteUnique([1, 3, 2], [5, 2, 1, 4], [2, 1]);`

Espero le sirv a a alguien en el futuro!!!

Answer (score 0):

A ver checa si esto te ayuda, lo único que hice fue agregar [ antes y ] después  de tu declaración de arreglo...  Así agrupo todos tus arreglos en uno solo...

```js
function uniteUnique(arr) {
  var newArr=[];
  var args = Array.from(arr);

  alert(args);

  for(i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
    if(Array.isArray(arr[i])){
      for(j=0;j<arr[i].length;j++){
        if(!newArr.includes(arr[i][j])){
          newArr.push(arr[i][j]);
        }
      }
    }else{
      newArr.push(arr[i]);
    }
  }
  return newArr;
}

$('#procesar').click(function(){
  var arr = uniteUnique([[1, 3, 2], [5, 2, 1, 4], [2, 1]]);
  $('#resultados').text(arr);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id='procesar'>Mostrar Resultados</button>

<br/>
<br/>
<div id='resultados'>
</div>
```

Comment: Es una buena solución el unico problema es que no se puede agregarle ni quitarle nada a la llamada de la funcion. Ya lo he resuelto si quiere puedes checar como quedo al final...

Comment: Ok, :)  que bueno que ya lo resolviste